# query for selecting specific row in group

Tags: sql

I need to get for each company_name and node_name the first text (the row who has the lowest row_id)  from table T_TBL_DATA. Something like:

```
SELECT company_name, node_name, [text]
FROM T_TBL_DATA
GROUP BY company_name, node_name
WHERE the selected [text] is from the row with the smallest row_id within each group
```

Any idea?

Comment: what id node or company???????????

Comment: @Royi Namir: row_id. I update the question.

Comment: @Naor just a thought, if your primary key of the table be one of company id or node id, logically you will be having a sequence on that. so if you can just take a minimum, you will get the best query according to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select company_id, node_id, [text]
from t_tbl_data
where row_id in
(
    select min(row_id)
    from t_tbl_data
    group by company_id, node_id
)
```

Comment: @Naor still not enough information, what determines how your rows are ordered??  What makes a company_id/node_id combination the top??

Comment: For each company_name and node_name in the table, I need the text of the first created row (I can determine that by the row_id column).

Comment: @Naor ok if `row_id` is a field in your table, the edited answer should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming id is unique.
Database agnostic solution to some degree:

```
select
    company_id, node_id, (select txt from T_TBL_DATA t2 where t2.id =  min(t1.id))
from T_TBL_DATA t1
group by company_id, node_id
```

For MS SQL Server 2005 and higher a little bit simpler:

```
-- =============
-- sample data
-- =============
declare @t table
(
    id int,
    company_id int,
    node_id int,
    txt varchar(50)
)

insert into @t values (1, 1, 1, 'abc1')
insert into @t values (2, 1, 1, 'abc2')
insert into @t values (3, 1, 2, 'abc3')
insert into @t values (4, 1, 2, 'abc4')
insert into @t values (5, 2, 1, 'abc5')
insert into @t values (6, 2, 1, 'abc6')
insert into @t values (7, 2, 2, 'abc7')
insert into @t values (8, 2, 2, 'abc8')

-- =============
-- solution
-- =============
select
    company_id, node_id, txt
from
(
    select 
        *,
        id2 = min(id) over(partition by company_id, node_id)
    from @t
) t
where id = id2
```